# Cannot find module 'lodash.isequal'

Tags: angular

When I add module [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/tree/master/src/app/modules) folder in my project I got an error Cannot find module 'lodash.isequal' in compile time. I'm install lodash but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just gone through your code and tried `lodash` and **its working**.

**Do the follow steps:**

**Step 1:** Go to your project dir and run command:

`npm install lodash --save`

**Step 2:** Now goto you component file where you want to import `lodash`.

**Import on top of the file as :**

`import _ from 'lodash';`

**Step 3:** Now use your lodash as in this component:

```
_.find(this.columnDefinitions, function (device) {
  if(device.id==='duration'){
    console.log("device",device);
  }
});
```

I used it in your `GridAddItemComponent` component.

That's it.

Now you can use anywhere as above.

Snapshots:

**Import:**
[image: Import]

**Use:**
[image: Use]

**Result:**
[image: Result]

Your Project:[image]